# change python OrderedDict sort to be alphabetical and numerical

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

Currently doing the following:

```
import collections
dict = {'alex1':'thing1','alex2':'thing2','alex11':'thingy','adam1':'foo','adam3':'bar','adam22':'drew'}
od = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(dict.items()))
for key,val in od.items():
    print key
```

And getting the following

```
adam1
adam22
adam3
alex1
alex11
alex2
```

Which is sorted, but I would like it to be:

```
adam1
adam3
adam22
alex1
alex2
alex11
```

Where it is both alphabetical and numerical order.  How can I achieve this?

Comment: How can it be correct if it isn't what you want?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate - if the linked answer is not sufficient, just edit and I'll vote to re-open.

Comment: solution was in duplicate of duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836710/does-python-have-a-built-in-function-for-string-natural-sort